# Minimization Problem in Matlab regarding vector equation

Tags: optimization, matlab

How can I minimize for b in the equation

```
    f(b) = norm((b*a+c),2)
```

when b is a scalar and c, a are vectors (Nx1)?

I tried:

```
    objective_fct = @(beta_min)(norm((b*a+c),2))

    [beta_min,fval] = fminsearch(objective_fct,[-ones(6,1), ones(6,1)])
```

but that doesn't work...

Comment: Isn't $f$ just quadratic in $b$? Why do you need a computer to minimize it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ${\bf a}\neq 0$, the minimum of $f(b)$ is $||{\bf c}||^2 - {({\bf a}\cdot {\bf c})^2\over ||{\bf a}||^2}$. This is attained at $b = -({\bf a}\cdot{\bf c})/||{\bf a}||^2$.

Here are the steps:
$$||b{\bf a} + {\bf c}||^2 = (b{\bf a}+{\bf c})\cdot (b{\bf a}+{\bf c}) = ||{\bf a}||^2 b^2 + 2({\bf a}\cdot{\bf c})b + ||{\bf c}||^2.$$
The right-hand side is quadratic in $b$ and (assuming ${\bf a}\neq 0$) concave up. Find the minimum by taking the derivative with respect to $b$ and setting it equal to zero: $$2||{\bf a}||^2b + 2{\bf a}\cdot{c} = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad b = -{({\bf a}\cdot{\bf c})\over ||{\bf a}||^2}\,.$$

Evaluating the quadratic at this value of $b$ gives the answer $||{\bf c}||^2 - {({\bf a}\cdot{\bf c})^2\over ||{\bf a}||^2}$ as above.

In other words, it would seem that you can just enter the formula for the minimum explicitly, without needing to call any optimization routine.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x)=||xa+c||_2=\sqrt{\sum_i (xa_i+c_i)^2}\geq 0$, you've got, calling $g(x)=f^2(x)$:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}g(x)=0\Rightarrow \sum_i2(xa_i+c_i)a_i=0,
$$
then:
$$
\sum_i(xa_i^2+a_ic_i)=x\sum a^2_i+\sum a_ic_i=0,
$$
finally:
$$
x=-\frac{\sum a_ic_i}{\sum a^2_i}=-\frac{a\cdot c}{||a||_2^2}.
$$

Comment: Couple of notes on this - (1) OP has a plus sign before the $c$, so important to note the minus sign in this response. (2) Is there an errant factor of $c_i$ in the denominator of the final result?

Comment: Yes, I wrote $c_i$ times $a_i$, and so there was an extra $c_i$ in denominator term. I also miswrote the sign of $c$, sorry, just edited.

Comment: OK looks great.